# how to put chrome devtool in browser?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm working for a project which run by chrome headless driver puppeteer, And i recently found a website (https://chrome.browserless.io/) could show puppeteer process in browser. This website appended an chrome devtoll which looks like magic.

i try to figure out how did work, and i found that this website inject a chrome devtool iframe, and the url usually like below:

`https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@7f3cdc3f76faecc6425814688e3b2b71bf1630a4/inspector.html?wss=chrome.browserless.io/devtools/page/(4BDC5841A823B95BF9B6107801819A31)&remoteFrontend=true`

i think the version after inspector.html refer for the puppeteer code, but i don't know how this work.

i think this is some method imply over [DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). I search the document but found nothing about how to put chrome devtool iframe in browser.

Does anyone know how to do this? or any document about this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Browserless Chrome Debugger](https://chrome.browserless.io/) you mentioned in your question has an instance of [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) text editor embedded in the left hand section.

In the right hand section, an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element exists to display the result of the code you executed.

[image: Browserless Chrome Debugger]

Simply put, you can simulate this type of behavior and allow users to execute Puppeteer code directly from your website by following a series of steps:

- [Sandbox a section of your system](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-lxd-on-ubuntu-16-04) with a system container manager, such as [LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/).
- [Install Node.js, NPM, and Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343709/4283581).
- Install a web-based code editor, like [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/), and embed it into a web page.
- Validate and send an AJAX request with the code from the text editor to your sandbox server.
- Sanitize the code, and then pass the code to Puppeteer.
- Return the result to your callback function in your AJAX request on the client-side.
- Format and sanitize the result before displaying it in an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

> **Note:** This is a naive implantation of this concept intended to explain the bare necessities of what would be required to obtain the goal in the question.
>
> Make sure that you follow all generally recommended security practices.