# npm install puppeteer showing permission denied errors

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I'm unable to install `puppeteer` as a project dependency, and I've tried re-installing node. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Running Ubuntu 17.10 x64

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs;
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -;
apt-get install -y nodejs;
sudo npm install -g n;
sudo n stable;
```

Node versions:

```
$ node -v
v9.4.0
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

I try to install:

```
root@server:/var/www/html# npm install --save puppeteer
```

Error message:

```
> puppeteer@1.1.0 install /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r536395! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium' }
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No description

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.1.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-19T15_55_52_669Z-debug.log
```

I don't see any ways to fix this in the referenced issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/375

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT 20th April 2019:**

The easy solution suggested by lauraalvarezz1 is,

```
sudo npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true
```

This is okay as long as you trust puppeteer and want it to install puppeteer globally.

However beware of using `--unsafe-perm=true` for permission related problems. Reasons are:

- Running unsafe-perm=true with sudo, as a non-root user, will give the script root access. This might be okay only if you trust the script and do not concern about security that much.
- You might need to use `--no-sandbox` in every script you run, because the chrome installed with this command might not run without this parameter. See this [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3443).

---

You have installed npm with `sudo`. Thus anything you install globally will require `sudo`.

To install anything on `var/www/html` folder, either you have to own that folder,

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/html
```

Or you can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage npm. Technically it will use your home directory and your current user.

After installing nvm, you can install puppeteer globally with it,

```
npm i -g puppeteer
```

or you have to use sudo

```
sudo npm install --save puppeteer
```

However chromium will not be downloaded due to permission error, that's why you have to use `---unsafe-perm=true` as stated before.

Security Related Resources:

- Resolve this without sudo, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13021677/6161265).
- Learn more about best practices dealing with /var/www folder, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/663547).

Best of luck!

Comment: Recursively changing the owner for **every file on the system**? Surely you meant `./` at least

Comment: Sorry, fixed :D

Comment: unsafe-perm=true has some (security) drawbacks and that's why I did not update my answer last year, even if it's a quick solution. The accepted and most upvoted answer, both are correct. All links in my answer are from SO for more resource.

Comment: "some (security) drawbacks"  - it may be not a problem if people run the code that did not get sufficient scrutiny in a VM, as they should.

Comment: sudo + global is a very bad hack

Comment: Yes this answer explains this. ^

Answer (score 9):

Run this on your terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true
```

Comment: sudo + global is unsafe

Answer (score 3):

Before you begin, make sure you have the most recent version of Node.js.

The [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#usage) states:

> Note: Puppeteer requires at least Node v6.4.0, but the examples below use async/await which is only supported in Node v7.6.0 or greater.

You can check which version of Node.js you have using the following command:

```
node -v
# OR nodejs -v
```

If your version of Node.js is less then v7.6.0, you can [completely uninstall your current version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/4283581).

Then, you can use complete the [reinstallation using a PPA](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04#installing-using-a-ppa):

```
sudo apt update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install build-essential
```

You can check the new versions of Node.js and NPM installed on your system:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Finally, you can install Puppeteer:

```
sudo npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Now you can run Puppeteer scripts using the `node` command:

```
node puppeteer-script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I did:

1. `yarn install --ignore-scripts`
2. `yarn install`.

And it worked without `sudo` or global package installation.

It should work with `npm` too.

I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: pretty sure the error message you're getting will tell you what directory needs permissions to be written to. it working with `sudo` means that the user you're using to install scripts does not have permissions to write to the directory.

Comment: I cloned repository, so there should not be any permissions restrictions. Here is the output of groups command:
artem_ganev : artem_ganev adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker